# Providing login_hint option for Google Oauth2 redirect

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I'm passing in `login_hint=1` option as part of Oauth2 request query string but this doesn't appear when I receive a callback from Google Oauth2 after accepting it.

I'm only getting:
`google/oauth2callback?code=4/vadsdaalijfqwo8fdjqojcxadassddsa#`

I was expecting `1` (which is user id) to come back as part of callback.

How do I make sure I get this hint back after redirect in my callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the variable to [`state`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl). In the callback argument, you can parse your variable from `state` argument.

For example,

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email profile&state={"user_id": 1}&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&approval_prompt=force`

The callback url will be `http://localhost/code?state={"user_id": 1}&code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7`

Comment: In your state dictionary, you should also include a `nonce` alongside the `user_id`, and check that you get the same nonce back (to protect against CSRF). See the documentation of state here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer